# Hardening GnuPG against brute force attacks

Tags: gnupg, python

I am currently working on a python program that utilizes GnuPG (with symmetric encryption) to store data on the client: User supplies password, gpg file is decrypted, data is loaded, etc.

Say an attacker copies this gpg file. What can be done to slow down brute forcing of the password? Maybe it is possible to do thousands of iterations in a PBKDF (or maybe SHA), then use that as the password?

Comment: GnuPG already uses (PGP's version of) iterated, salted PBKDF -- see the 's2k' items at https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Options.html and [rfc4880 section 3.7.1.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.3)

Comment: The encrypted gpg file is not the issue. On the other hand, if an attacker obtains the **private** key that was used to encrypt the file, a brute force attack becomes possible. All will then depend on the strength of your passphrase. So you have to protect that key well.

Comment: The author of the answer you accepted asked that the answer be deleted because it is wrong.